Plotting a bar chart superimposed on a line chart
I have two dataframes, both of them indexed by a timestamp. I want to plot one of them as a bar chart and the other as a line chart along the same x axis (but with different y scales). I thought the following would work...
ax = df[ts1:ts2].plot(y='A', kind='bar')
df2[ts1:ts2].plot(y='B', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)

But this only ends up plotting the bar chart. If I don't include kind='bar' in the first line it does basically work. But I would really like for it to a bar chart

Could you please share some reproducible data?

See e.g. Plotting lines and bars from pandas dataframe on same graph using matplotlib. Everything heavily depends on the type of the index.
